# How can I use a PHP script in typo3 v9?

Tags: php, typo3

I'd like to know if there is a way to use a PHP script in the typo3 v9 or a newer version.
If possible, I'd prefer a way to call a function and not to embed the code in an HTML box.

Thanks a lot

Comment: You should add more details what exactly you tried to do and what problems you have encountered.

Comment: I have written some PHP functions and collected them in a file. With these functions, I can create custom graphics and forms which I now want to integrate into a typo3 v9 webpage.

Comment: Yes you can. https://youtu.be/15_HsnC_60Q for more answer, add more question.

Comment: I love it, thank you so much :)

Comment: I think this question can be split up into two parts: 1. Should you even consider using a PHP script in TYPO3 and what are the possible usecases and 2. How can you do it? - I don't want to clutter up this question, but question 1a interests me so I added this as separate question:

Comment: The answer to your comment: 1. If you operate your own website you may want to add own applications. 2. you can use the link provided by bandanh  youtu.be/15_HsnC_60Q   It is a guide to write your own extension with PHP since TYPO3 removed the option to include PHP files directly.

Answer (score 1):

A short history:

in earlier days (TYPO3 prior to 4.2) there was a PHP content element. As of the possibility to insert bad code it was removed.

then there was a possibilty to include any file with PHP code by typoscript as a `userfunc`.

That was restricted by TYPO3 6 as you now can only use methods of classes as `userfunc`.

For usage in the front end you can build a plugin, so the editor can use a `function` (with parameters) as desired. or include it by typoscript (`userfunc`) where you need it. This can be easily done with an [extension](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=15_HsnC_60Q) (as bandanh commented), so your code is deployable and can be included in any installation.